# Upload a xml file into logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

i already upload my xml file into logtsahs, everything sames okey 
but the result is not like i want,

because i want to specify to each tag to a column so i can do my search in kibana using a name of a column but not searching in all document .

This is the result in kibana :

```
  {
        "_index": "tizer",
        "_type": "tizerlfiles",
        "_id": "AWhvriZgrW4BZjJkO214",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "DESKTOP-2LL9494",
          "path": "D:/test.xml",
          "@timestamp": "2019-01-21T09:11:50.242Z",
          "message": """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:Invoicing xmlns:tns="xxx">
    <tns:FileNumber>20180919093512</tns:FileNumber>
    <tns:FileDate>2018-09-19</tns:FileDate>
    <tns:Forwarder>DBS</tns:Forwarder>
    <tns:Invoice>
        <tns:InvoicingDate>"2018-09-17"</tns:InvoicingDate>
        <tns:InvoicingBranch>SJCPTY</tns:InvoicingBranch>
        <tns:InitialInvoiceNumber>0</tns:InitialInvoiceNumber>
        <tns:ChanelInvoicingRefrence>257805</tns:ChanelInvoicingRefrence>
        <tns:FFInvoiceLineRefrence>01041000</tns:FFInvoiceLineRefrence>
        <tns:PayerAccountNameCode>200111</tns:PayerAccountNameCode>
        <tns:BusinessDivision>FA</tns:BusinessDivision>
        <tns:ETD>2018-09-16</tns:ETD>
        <tns:ETA>2018-09-16</tns:ETA>
        <tns:TypeConsignee>Other</tns:TypeConsignee>
        <tns:Consignee>EUROPERFUMERIA</tns:Consignee>
        <tns:Customer>OTHER</tns:Customer>
        <tns:Departure>
            <tns:CountryCode>FR</tns:CountryCode>
            <tns:CodePostal>95470</tns:CodePostal>
            <tns:City>VEMARS</tns:City>
            <tns:Address>"P.A. des Portes de Vemars CR9. Rue de la Haie Marteau "</tns:Address>
            <tns:Airport>
                <tns:Code>CDG</tns:Code>
                <tns:Denomination>FRANCE</tns:Denomination>
            </tns:Airport>
            <tns:Region>EMEA</tns:Region>
        </tns:Departure>
    </tns:Invoice>
""",
          "tags": [
            "multiline"
          ]
        }
```

This is my config file :

[configfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYJ63.png)

```
input {
 file {
  path => "D:/test.xml"
  start_position => beginning
  sincedb_path => "NUL"
  codec => multiline {
  pattern => "<invoicing>|</invoicing>"
  negate => "true"
  what => "previous"
  auto_flush_interval => 1
  max_lines => 3000
  }

 }
}


filter {
  xml {
   source => "message"
   target => "message.parsed"
   store_xml => false
   force_array => false

  }

}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
elasticsearch {
  index => "tizer"
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  document_type => "tizerlfiles"
 }
}
```

Comment: Post your configuration as text instead of a picture.

Comment: Don't use a dot in a field name (message`.`parsed), I think it's not supported by elasticsearch.

Comment: this is my config file in up @baudsp

Comment: Why are you using `store_xml => false`(cf https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-xml.html#plugins-filters-xml-store_xml)? With this option, the result of the parsing will not be stored.

Comment: i need to change it to be store_xml => true right??

Comment: Yes. Or just remove it, its default value is `true`